# What is known about the Green or the White?

Tags: lore, 13th-age

I am new to *13th Age* and I was interested in a bit of lore in the "default" setting.

In the description of *The Elven Queen* and *The Three* there is only a passing mention of the imprisonment of *The Green* (and also that *The White* was killed by *The Witch King*).

I would like to know more of when the The Three were Four, or Five. What would happen if the The Green was freed? I think that those could be good tracks to orient long epic adventures.

Can the Green be considered an Icon? What is its relationship to the Three? Would its reappearance be necessarily bad for the the Great Gold Wyrm?

So basically any material from the source of the *13th Age* setting is welcome.

Comment: It's not an answer to the question, but you can see the write-up for white dragons (a *Bestiary* sneak preview) at http://www.pelgranepress.com/site/media/pdfs/bestiarypreview_wdragon_nov25.pdf. White dragons aren't just ice dragons; they're cemetery dragons and moon dragons, too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### The default setting is left purposefully vague

It presents a starting point to which you can add. As such, the passing mentions and throw-away lines are meant to be an inspiration for the reader, and don't necessarily have any further background information. Here are a couple of quotes to support this:

On the names of Icons (page 195):

> Ordinarily one of our published campaign settings
>   would choose names for key NPCs that evoke
>   wonder and a sense of a specific individual history.
>   But we didn’t choose that route for 13th Age. Instead
>   we chose somewhat generic names for the icons to
>   leave room for you to customize icon identities in
>   each of your campaigns.

On adding to the map (page 257):

> If you decide to use our world instead of a world you’ve already got
>   cooking, don’t treat our map as restrictive. The apparently empty
>   sections of our map shouldn’t be empty in your world.

It is also worth pointing out that currently only the core rulebook has been published. It is entirely possible things will get more fleshed out in the future. This shouldn't discourage you from inventing your own stories, though. With that in mind...

### If the Green returned

Another quote, from the green dragons description:

> Green dragons have drifted far from
>   their draconic roots. Without an iconic
>   dragon to inspire them, they have become
>   increasingly isolated from dragonkind. In
>   fact, they frequently ally with neutral or evil
>   creatures, but not with other sorts of dragons.
>   Other dragons consider the greens lost. Green
>   dragons consider the others to be yesterday’s news.

As an idle speculation, then, the return of the Green could result in a civil war among the green dragons, perhaps even causing other dragons to take sides, and potentially overturn the Three/Four.

Comment: So The Three would not assist a plot to free the Green dragon? Is there no Icon that would be in that favour? I could see the Prince of Shadows do that, or the High Druid, if she saw the Green as a possible ally in bringing chaos to the human civilization?

Comment: Depending on your interpretation of the Icons, a narrative justification can be made for any of them going either way. Perhaps The Three don't want to share their greater power. Perhaps they free The Green, only to find out it's fallen in love with the Elf Queen. Perhaps its captivity has been a ruse all along. That's the point - it's up to you, there's no canonical version. You could ask another question here: "What would various Icons think of freeing the Green?" Though, again, your Icons would be different from mine.

Comment: Let's say I made a character which 1 unique thing is that he was prophecised to be the key in the liberation of the Green ... what would be IYO it's icons connections? Or which would it be interesting to leverage?

Comment: So here's a cool thing about 13th Age's approach. The relationships you choose for your character will affect the story. They may, in fact, end up indirectly determining the attitudes Icons take to The Green's return. So while a negative relationship with the Elf Queen and likely a complicated relationship with The Three are something of a given, the third one is up to you. Whichever Icon you choose will have a strong opinion.

Answer (score 3):

As Magician mentioned, we know almost nothing about the Green and the White.

Well, we know a little. The Green is imprisoned by the Elf Queen (18, 26), and is associated with poison.

The White was killed by the Lich King, and turned into an undead (26). It is associated with cold. There are still cults and religions devoted to the White (273), but are more in denial than looking at some current, glorious, figure.

The Green is by far the most flexible of these. After all, it's still alive, and I'm assuming that's a huge step on the path to power in the 13th Age (undead are powerful, but with the Lich King I'd doubt that even a dragon could break free that easily). Were it to rise to power it'd likely hold a huge grudge against the Elf Queen or be plainly and purely evil. Alternatively, as it is a thrall of the Elf Queen, it could rise as a puppet Icon or perhaps be used in a war against the Lich King.

We don't know much about Green's relationships. His reappearance would be a little awkward, I'd imagine, at least for certain parties. The Great Gold Wyrm may or may not care; so long as he isn't attacked and his followers are not harassed he's usually pretty easy going and occupied by the whole "I'm stuck keeping demons from killing everyone and eating their spleens" thing. For The Three, they don't seem like the "Welcome back to the group!" kind of dragons, so I'm betting there would be a new rivalry, especially if the Green and White returned to prominence as Icons around the same time. At the same time, I doubt that the Green would even care to return to The Three; green dragons tend not to get along with the rest of dragonkind, and are very arrogant about it. This probably played a role in his capture in the first place.

The White is dead, but it's implied to have been resurrected. We don't know how much free will that something on the scale of a reanimated dragon has; lower-level undead have little, while something like a true vampire has more. It's realistic to say that it's likely to make an appearance, but not be on the same level of former glory. It will likely appear as a villain, either of its own accord or operating in allegiance with the Lich King.

Were the White to return independently, he would likely try to recover his former glory; he was almost certainly an Icon, or at least a lower-case-I-icon, so there's no reason he couldn't lead his own faction. Depending on the mood and time, he could be evil and corrupted, or something more like the Crusader, or even potentially reject the Lich King's ways and become a "good" character, but that's all speculative. Either way, if the White returns, he's already got a framework to build on.